# Bash script top IP address in a web log file

Tags: bash, shell, logging

Hi I'm a total novice when it comes to scripting and am trying to work out how you would read the top 10 I.P addresses in a web log file. I know it would need to loop each line and count until the number there's a top 10. I've just got no idea how to go about it.

If anyone has an idea that would be appreciated, just go get me started.

There would probably be thousands of lines, here's a sample of a few.

```
121.45.49.36 - - [26/Feb/2013:09:07:21 +1100] "GET /jpg4/dsc1222s.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 9335
121.45.49.36 - - [26/Feb/2013:09:07:21 +1100] "GET /jpg4/dsc1217s.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 9540
121.45.49.36 - - [26/Feb/2013:09:07:22 +1100] "GET /jpg4/dsc3369s.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 11938
121.45.49.36 - - [26/Feb/2013:09:07:22 +1100] "GET /jpg4/dsc1294s.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 11184
```

Comment: There are *many* Apache log analysis frameworks, maybe look into if one of them can be used for your purpose?

Comment: Important question: is each line going to be structured excactly in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

This will print the IP address and the number of occurences of it.

```
awk 'END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}{a[$1]++}' file
```

Didnt read the question properly, for top 10 use

```
awk 'END{for(i in a)print a[i],i }{a[$1]++}' test | sort -rn | head -10
```

Comment: For the OP: You might also want to read about [`sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) and [`head`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to select top IP addresses appearing anywhere in the file, you can use this one liner:

```
grep -oE '\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b' file | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10'
```

Comment: @Jidder if you meant the sort was backwards, yes, you are right.  I fixed it - should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the IP is always on the far left side:

```
cut -f1 -d ' ' | sed "/.*[a-zA-Z].*/d" | sort | uniq
```

1. `cut` keeps only the left value from each line.
2. `sed` removes all lines with a character (in case of domains).
3. `sort | uniq` remove duplicate IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it in Awk:

```
awk '$1 ~ /[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/ {
    n++
    if(n<=10)
        print $1
    else
        exit
}' log
```

Will print the first 10 IP addresses that are found in the first column.